# UWP database of music library storage

Tags: database, win-universal-app, state

I want to know that how can I achieve following functionality in a c#/xaml UWP app.

1. when the app runs first time it scans all of the music library, folders and files and stuff.
2. Then it stores in some kind of database at backend.
3. so whenever u launch app again, it doesnt have to scan again everytime, and it just runs and it already has all the necessary data.
4. i am guessing that a sqlite database can be used in applicationdata.localfolder
5. but is there a way that I can save the state and data of all the visual elements of all the pages of my app somewhere in a better way? so that everytime app launches it appears that it was just minimized and then maximized?

thanks in advance.

Comment: See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries. For your first point. First link has how to fetch all songs and 2nd one has background audio task details.

Comment: I really appreciate the links @Archana but I actually already know everything abt knownfolders, what I want to know that, my app should extract files from knownfolders only on the first run of the app, and must have the data already every time I run the app again. and also how can I save the data bound to my gridviews and listviews etc, so that next time I just initialize them quickly instead of looping through and assigning value to each item. thankyou

Comment: Save the meta data of songs(name,Path etc)to database table on first launch. On subsequent launch compare the songs count returned from Music API and database table. If it is same fetch from database or else you have to fetch from API It will be much faster on second launch

Comment: You have to do first launch operation that is looping through songs collection returned from API and saving to database in async Task so that it won't hang UI

Comment: I think if you take data  bound to gridview and list view from database ( Assuming songs data) it won't be that time consuming. You can do similar way for Albums collection also

Comment: that really helped me all of the information, thankyou so much, I really do appreciate all the help. everything u suggested totally makes sense and yes i will do that, just a few more point i have if u can clarify them plz
1. can i save storagefile in db? instead of the metadata of file? because even if i retrieve from db, i would need storagefile to play the file.and i guess getfilefrompath() method will do that for me, (considering, that path belongs within music library folder) right?.
so is there a way that on first launch i save storagefile along with its thumbnail in db?

Comment: No you can't store storagefile to db.. There is no such compatible type in sqllite. Instead that you can store the path of the song. Actually you have to use path to play the song instead of StorageFile. MediaPlayer play method also takes path to play the song as Uri. Check that

Comment: I ll add that as answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the meta data of songs(name,Path etc)to database table on first launch. On subsequent launch compare the songs count returned from Music API and database table. If it is same fetch from database or else you have to fetch from API It will be much faster on second launch
You have to do first launch operation that is looping through songs collection returned from API and saving to database in async Task so that it won't hang UI
No you can't store storagefile to db.. There is no such compatible type in sqllite. Instead that you can store the path of the song. Actually you have to use path to play the song instead of StorageFile. MediaPlayer play method also takes path to play the song as Uri. Check that.

Comment: can u please show me a code snippet that how media element plays directly from path? :)

Comment: BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/Ring02.wma")); BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play() check this link http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player

Comment: Hope you are using BackGroundMediaPlayer to play the songs